# instalar paque tidyr o tidyverse

Tags: r

Necesito una ayuda. Estoy tratando de instalar los paquetes tidyr o tidyverse y no he podido. Adjunto muestro la imagen. Tengo instalado windows 7 y mi version de R es 4.03. A veces el programa se cuelga y se cierra solo(deja de funcionar).Que podria estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta instalar los paquetes que se mencionan en el error, por ejemplo `install.packages('colorspace')`

Comment: Gracias Patricio.Lo intento y luego aviso